# Use USB keyboard for text input in Smart TV application

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

My application has implemented custom onscreen-keyboard.

Is there a way to support the USB keyboard connected to a TV? By default, Samsung TV translates some keystrokes to remote control codes (0-9, red, blue, etc..). Is there a way to get all keystrokes? Preferably without the use of IME.

UPDATE:
I want to implement text input from the USB keyboard within my own onscreen virtual keyboard. By default, letter keys are not translated to application.

TV: UE46ES8000, USB, and BT keyboards connected and allow to control application, but unable to input text in it.

Comment: Just to double check. You are saying that USB keyboard works, but some keystrokes are converted to remote codes (instead of being passed directly to your app)?

Comment: Yes, Samsung keycodes for numbers and cursor arrows on remote control differs from ordinary keyboard keycodes. And USB-connected keyboard in `keydown` events send remote codes.

Comment: You need to provide some info on which API you are using, and also the runtime environment.

Comment: My guess is Samsung developers re-defined input event code as something non-standard. This basically means this TV is by (poor) design not meant to be used with a standard USB keyboard. If you are make an application for the public then you really should't be targeting this TV/keyboard combination, because non of your target users will expect it to work, and it's not your fault that it doesn't, and even you get it to work, your app won't sell because it doesn't work with Samsung's proprietary keyboard that the users actually buys for the TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected keyboard acts as remote control, with changed key codes.

Keyboard input more can be changed:
Samsung IME library changes mode when inputs text. But it uses undocumented API to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect keybords to your SmartTV but your TV need to support them.

In example this samsung keybord: http://www.samsung.com/uk/consumer/tv-audio-video/television/tv-accessories/VG-KBD1500/XU-spec?subsubtype=wireless-keyboard

is compatible with:

```
Samsung SMART TV: LED ES6100 series and above, PDP E550 series and above
```

So if your TV device support USB or wireless keybord you do not need to translate any key codes in your application it will just work.